# How to convert a simple method into a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion

Ive created this code that finds the number of animals given the number of heads and legs

```
public class howmanyAnimals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int Heads = 100;
        int legs = 300;

        int animals = animalHeads(Heads, legs);
        System.out.println("Number of cows: " + animals);
        System.out.println("Number of chickens: "+ (Heads - animals));
    }

    static int animalHeads(int heads, int legs) {

       int count = 0;
      count = (legs) - 2 * (heads);
        count = count / 2;
        return count; 



    }

}
```

output:

```
Number of cows: 50
Number of chickens: 50
```

This works fine however the method animalHeads needs to be Recurive

I attempted this method

```
 static int animalHeads(int heads, int legs) {

        int count = 0;
        count = (legs) - 2 * (heads);
        count = count / 2;

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (count % 2 != 0) {
            return count = animalHeads(100, 300);
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

but im a bit rusty with recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `animalHeads` actually calculates the number of cows.

Since a cow has 1 head and 4 legs, the recursive step should be:

```
animalHeads(heads, legs) = 1 + aminalHeads(heads - 1, legs - 4);
```

However, since the heads and legs count include chickens, which have 1 head and 2 legs, the recursion should end when all the remaining heads and legs belong to chickens, which happens when the remaining number of legs is twice the remaining number of heads.

```
static int animalHeads(int heads, int legs) 
{
    if (heads * 2 == legs) { // only chickens are left
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + animalHeads(heads - 1, legs - 4);
}
```

Comment: Whats the best way to learn recurrisve? I have an exam in 3 days and its the only thing thats stumping me a bit. I understand basic recurssive problems like factorial and fibonacci and even tower of Hanoi but as they get harder i get confused.

Comment: @DavidLing You have to think how to break a problem into instances of the same problem, but with smaller input. In this example, I showed you how to solve `animalHeads(int heads, int legs)` with a recursive call to `animalHeads(heads - 1, legs - 4)`.